# Displaying a randomly selected line from a .txt document in java

Tags: random, java.util.scanner

I have a .txt document that holds a list of words, one word on each line. There are ten lines. How do I read this document, pick a random line from it, and have that word displayed?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
    Scanner fileScan, wordScan;
    String word;
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pickedLine = rand.nextInt(6)+1;

    fileScan = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));


    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {
        word = fileScan.nextLine();
        System.out.println()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd scan each line into an array, then get a random number between 0 and the array length - 1. I'd then use that number to get a line from that array that corresponds to that number. I'm not sure how you want to display the line of text, though.

NOTE: Not complete source code. You must declare the array above.

```
var currentLine = 0;
while (fileScan.hasNext()) 
{
    word = fileScan.nextLine();

    newArray[currentLine] = word;
    currentLine++;
}
```

Comment: my .txt document is very simple, it has one 5 letter word on each line, and there are only 10 lines. I just want a random word to be displayed for which I need to use println

Comment: Just code what I said above and your program should come along just great.

Comment: Oh, I see. This little tutorial should get you going pretty quickly. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp I've edited my answer with a quick example

Comment: If I create an array then would I not by scanning from my text document anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as it's hard to understand your sentence. But from what I can tell you're asking, yes, you still need to read from the text document. Each time you read a line from the document, store that line of text into one spot in the array.

Comment: Is there a way to not use arrays? Like to simply generate a random number and then scan the corresponding line with that number?

Comment: I don't believe you can scan a specific line of a file. This is probably the best, and easiest way to do it.